# Update table in a SQL database

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I am trying to add a column in my table which maps some values in another column to the new column. (Population is another column that I have) This is what I have been using:

```
UPDATE my_table 
SET popmatch2 
    CASE 
       WHEN popmatch IN ('MFNR', 'GQNR', 'EWNR', 'MHNR', 'OUTONR', 'OUTADVNR') 
          THEN popmatch2 IN ('GENERAL', 'GENERAL', 'GENERAL', 'GENERAL', 'ENDEMIC', 'ENDEMIC') 
          ELSE POPULATION;
```

This is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The major problems with your current syntax is that you need to *assign* the `popmatach2` column to something.  In this instance, assigning to a `CASE` expression might make sense.  A `CASE` expression has to return a single value, not group of values, and each `WHEN` condition should return a single value.

```
UPDATE my_table
SET popmatch2 = CASE WHEN popmatch IN ('MFNR', 'GQNR', 'EWNR') THEN 'GENERAL'
                     WHEN popmatch IN ('OUTONR', 'OUTADVNR')   THEN 'ENDEMIC'
                     ELSE 'POPULATION' END;
```

You need to put single quotes around `POPULATION` if you intend for that to be a string literal.

Comment: ORA-00936: missing expression
42000/936 - hitting into this error now

Comment: @JDoe Reload your page.

Comment: Population is another column I am referring to. However, even with it as a string it's not working

Comment: What are the types of `popmatch2` and `POPULATION` ?  I didn't mention this, but both of these columns would have to be text in order for your `CASE` expression to work/make sense.

Comment: Both of these are texts.

Comment: I don't know why either of these answers is not working for you.  If you could perhaps setup a demo on SQLFiddle.com then maybe someone could take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct syntax:

```
update my_table 
   set popmatch2 = (case when popmatch in ('MFNR', 'GQNR', 'EWNR', 'MHNR')
                         then 'GENERAL'
                         when popmatch in ('OUTONR', 'OUTADVNR') 
                         then 'ENDEMIC'
                         else 'POPULATION'  -- I'm guessing this is really a string
                    end);
```

You probably want to do a `commit` after the update, so the changes are committed.

Notes:

- The `case` must have an `end`.
- The `then` should be a single string.
- Each `when` should result in a single string being returned.